# CakePHP “Object not found!” XAMP Windows

Tags: php, cakephp

I just got downloaded from the cloud an old CakePHP project, it was uploaded for someone else, and I need to have a copy of it in my PC.
The problem is that when I paste it in my XAMPP folder (C:\xampp\htdocs\theproject), it shows the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkNI2.png)

I'm not sure if you are able to see the image, but it says:

> **Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.**
>
> **Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4**

I'm using PHP 7.0.4 & 7.1.33

Cake PHP version 2.3.8.

Comment: It seems to me a problem with the .htaccess file. Did you check if it exists in your directory? Try to perform a standard cake design. See if you load the elements correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anser! Yes, it exists. I'll check that out and I'll let you know, thanks!